# How to inject data-model mock into spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-test

In my unit tests, I need to mock a data-model instance in a spring @Controller, else the return value of the @RequestMapping method gets wrong.

To do this I tried the following:

1. Create a User mock, which calls user.login() and needs to return "true"
2. Inject mock object in the LoginController
3. Stub the login method to return true
4. Perform POST /Login with MockMVC from spring test
5. verify that mockUser.login got called

Here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String updateUI(Locale locale, Model model, @RequestParam("username") String username,
      @RequestParam("hashedPW") String hashedPW, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    user = new User(username, username, hashedPW.getBytes(), LoginHandler.getInstance());

    boolean loginResult = user.login();
    if(loginResult == true) {
      return "profile";
    }
    String output = "Failed login (" + username + ") requested, locale = " + locale;
    log(output);
    return "home";
  }
```

and my initialization of mock objects with injection:

```
@Mock
  private User mockUser;

  @InjectMocks
  private LoginController injectedLoginController;


  @Before
  public void setup() throws ServletException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(injectedLoginController).build();
    LOGFILE = new File("logs/general.log");
  }
```

and finally the unit test:

```
@Test
  public void testLoginSuccess() throws Exception {
    String username = "Stefan";
    byte[] hashedPW = "".getBytes();
    when(mockUser.login()).thenReturn(true);
    ResultActions ra = mvc
        .perform(post("/Login").param("username", username).param("hashedPW", hashedPW.toString()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(mockUser).login();
  }
```

All together I expected the User object that is handled by the controller to be of mockUser type instead of User, and the login() method to get called once (accordingly) and return "true".

But all I get is 
"Wanted but not invoked: mockUser.login()
 Actually, there was zero interaction with this mock."

I appreciate any suggestions to solve my problem since I am working on this for quite some time now and I don't seem to get the trick.

Comment: If you remove that last line `verify(mockUser).login();` , Do you pass this test?

Comment: The reason why the mock isn't called is due to the line `user = new User(username, username, hashedPW.getBytes(), LoginHandler.getInstance());` in your code. If you see there, a new object is instantiated. Hence the method from the mock object would never be called.

Comment: You haven't shown us where you inject your mock user to the controller. Even if you do, you overwrite it with a new instance of a User

Comment: Thanks for all your help!
@yuanqingfei : yes, it passes without this line.

Comment: @Lesiak : I thought the annotations Mock and InjectMocks do the injection if I got that right, can you confirm that?

Comment: @Magelan These annotations indeed can be used to inject mocks, but you haven't shown the injection point (if you inject the user there). The fact that you use a constructor to create a new user suggests that you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** This seems to be an IT test.. you should not force any injection.. spring does that:

```
@InjectMocks
private LoginController injectedLoginController;
```

**2)** You need to spy on your controller:

```
@SpyBean
private LoginController injectedLoginController;
```

**3)** You need to move the creation of the `User` to a package level method inside the controller:

```
user = createUser(username, username, hashedPW.getBytes(), LoginHandler.getInstance()); 


...

User createUser(...){
   return new User(username, username, hashedPW.getBytes(), LoginHandler.getInstance());
}
```

**4)** Make that method return a mocked User:

```
  doReturn(mockUser).when(injectedLoginController).createUser(...);
  when(mockUser.login()).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: Would the mock be called at all? since in the SUT, the User object gets instantiated with a new User(..

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, your help made me think of the solution I am currently running. I created a static UserFactory, so I am able to inject the mocked User and UserFactory and modify their method results. I read about spies, but I try to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Good man, they have thier place but in legacy code where you cannot change much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code, you can take help from `PowerMockito` which can help to mock construction of new objects.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({User.class})
public class ControllerUnderTest {
  // here User is class for which we want to mock object creation
}
```

Now, let's mock object

```
@Test
public void testLoginSuccess() throws Exception {
 ....
 User userMock = PowerMockito.createMock(User.class);

 PowerMockito.whenNew(User.class).withArguments(username, username, hashedPW.getBytes(), LoginHandler.getInstance()).thenReturn(userMock);

 expect(userMock.login()).andReturn(true);

 verify(mockUser).login();
 ...
}
```

For more details on `powermock`, please check this [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I took some time to read about PowerMockito now. I am sure this would work, but this would just compensate for bad design on my side. I got another solution running now.